# Reverse Array Sum

Tags: code-golf, array

Your program should take an array as input.

The array:

1. Will always be 1 dimensional
2. Will only contain integers
3. Can be empty

The program should reverse the array, and then add up the elements to the original for example:

**Input:** `[1, 2, 3]`

**Original:** `[1, 2, 3]`

**Reversed:** `[3, 2, 1]`

```
[1, 2, 3]
 +  +  +
[3, 2, 1]

[1+3, 2+2, 3+1]
```

**Output:** `[4, 4, 4]`

---

**Test Cases:**

```
#In             #Out
[8, 92],        [100, 100]
[1, 2, 3],      [4, 4, 4]
[5, 24, 85, 6], [11, 109, 109, 11]
[],             []
[999],          [1998]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code (in bytes) wins!

Comment: J 3 bytes. Program is t. t=:+|.

Comment: @RichardDonovan Nice Answer! Can you submit as an answer instead of a comment please :)

Answer (score 13):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 20 bytes

*5 bytes save by changing to a point free as suggested by nimi*

```hs
zipWith(+)=<<reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0RFoyqzIDyzJENDW9PWxqYotSy1qDhVM9pQx0jHWMcw9v9/AA)

Comment: go pointfree: `zipWith(+)=<<reverse`.

Comment: @nimi Wow I didn't think to do that but thats pretty smart.

Comment: Where do I put the array? I tried arguments, and input on TIO

Comment: @NoahCristino I fixed the TIO.  This is a point-free function so you just put the input after the function however Haskell requires a `main` to compile.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out thanks!

Comment: Passed all tests!

Comment: @nimi I am trying to wrap my brain around the use of the bind here, can you offer an explanation how this magic works?!

Comment: @maple_shaft: we use `=<<` from the function monad which is defined as: `(=<<) f g x = f (g x) x`. Here, written in infix: `(zipWith(+) =<< reverse) x` -> `zipWith(+) (reverse x) x`.

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
+U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1879P///9GGOkY6JrEA)

or

```
+Ṛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/74c5Z////NzTWMdExBAA)
(thanks @Mr. Xcoder for the second program)

#### explanation, though it's pretty self-explanatory

```
+U  Main link
+   Add, vectorizing, 
 U                    the input, reversed
```

```
+Ṛ  Main link
+   Add, vectorizing,
 Ṛ                    the input, reversed, without vectorizing (same thing for depth-1 lists)
```

For empty array `[]`, this outputs nothing. That is correct. Jelly's representation of an empty list is just simply nothing. Note that Jelly's representation of a list with a single element is just the element itself. Append `ŒṘ` to the code to see the Python internal representation of the output.

Comment: I found 2 issues. 1) When tested on `[9]` it outputs 18 instead of `[18]`, and 2) when tested on `[]` it doesn't output anything.

Comment: @NoahCristino It's not a full program, and there's already an explanation for that in the answer.

Comment: So I guess this is fine, it's just how Jelly outputs it

Comment: @NoahCristino Yeah. I added a part to the end of my answer so you can put that atom at the end of the code to see how Python would print it.

Comment: [`+Ṛ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/74c5Z////NzTWMdExBAA) works too.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yes, thanks. I'll write that in as well.

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```
a=>[...a].map(e=>e+a.pop())
```

```js
f=
a=>[...a].map(e=>e+a.pop())

console.log(f([8, 92])) // [100, 100]
console.log(f([1, 2, 3])) // [4, 4, 4]
console.log(f([5, 24, 85, 6])) // [11, 109, 109, 11]
console.log(f([])) // []
console.log(f([999])) //[1998]
```

Comment: Oh, man, I was *almost* there, but I didn't think to use the spread operator to do the clone.

Comment: Can you add the embedded try it for javascript?

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
Â+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cJP2///RhjoKRjoKxrEA)

Comment: Passed all my tests!

Comment: `R+` also works for 2 bytes.

Answer (score 9):

## Python 2, 32 bytes

```python
lambda l:map(sum,zip(l,l[::-1]))
```

Alternative solution without `zip` (35 bytes):

```python
lambda l:map(int.__add__,l,l[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIccqN7FAo7g0V6cqs0AjRycn2spK1zBWU/N/QVFmXolCmka0hY6lUawmF5xvqGOkY4wsYKpjZKJjYapjhiyIzLa0tIzV/A8A)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
lambda l:[i+j for i,j in zip(l,l[::-1])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY09DsMgFIN3TuExUV@H0B8FpJyEMqRqUV9EE5SwpJenlAov1mdLdtjja5llcsMt@fF9f4zw2vBhgltWME3gGR8OjSdvtD52trUpPre4YYARyDI9QUlLf@gIknCqeMl4JvTZrzWrrpSywgpRnn4/ZVeXMqw8R7iG2/QF)

The other, shorter Python answer replaces a list comprehension with `map`. Wish I'd thought to do that faster. ;-;

Comment: Passes all my tests!

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
mÈ+Ug~Y
```

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=bcgrVWd+WQ==&inputs=WzgsIDkyXQ==,WzEsIDIsIDNd,WzUsIDI0LCA4NSwgNl0=,W10=,Wzk5OV0=,WzEsMCwyXQ==&flags=LVE=) with the `-Q` flag to format the output array.

### Explanation

Implicit: `U` = input array

```
mÈ
```

Map the input by the following function...

```
+Ug
```

The value, plus the value in the input array at index...

```
~Y
```

`-(index+1)`, which gets elements from the end of the array.

Comment: Good job! I like the multiple input thing!

Comment: I really like the multiple-input Japt interpreter. Nice job!

Comment: That's really cool :-) I'd add that feature to the "official" interpreter, but with the current design it's sorta unextendable...

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->a{[*a].map{|i|i+a.pop}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdJCgIxEIXhfU5RS4cyaNqhs9CLxCClpO1A1MIJJMnZY8GD7/3Pz/nXhv2xLQ6U3Yy8vhHnEkuck@YH19qu4f2a8FQHuoynFO8hl1QUw@DClxIkr2pzK@zQ4A6XXsk32Ik9gjXiBsGsEXpxKymz1vo/)

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 12 bytes

```
Reverse@#+#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/KLUstag41UFZW1ntf0BRZl6JgkOagkO1hY6lUS0XkoChjpGOMYqIqY6RiY6FqY4ZAXUoHEtLy9r/AA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @xnor

```python
lambda l:[i+l.pop()for i in l*1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCsMgFET3fsUsk/YSiH0QA/kS6yKllV6wKombfL2RFDubw5mBiVv6BC@znR7Zzd/na4YbNZ9dF0NsWhsWMNjDnXqT03tNKyZogRI9EJQ09JOeIAmXqreiV8JQeK9dpVLKCCPE//z4HY8xLuwTbMNt3gE)

Comment: Passed all my tests good job :)

Comment: What an unusual method. `l*1` saves a byte.

Comment: I am having difficulties understanding the par `l*1`, any elaboration

Comment: @dhssa `l*1` makes a copy of the list `l`. If we would not make a copy, `pop()` would delete elements from the list before they were accessed in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I got it now. good trick to know for coding.

Comment: @dhssa If you want to copy a list in real python code, I would recommend you to use the functions provided by the `copy` module.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
↔;?z+ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HbFGv7Ku2HWyf8/x9tqGOkYxz7PwoA)

Comment: Passes all cases, cool name.

Answer (score 5):

## J, 3 bytes

```
+|.
```

Reverse, sum.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0G7Ro8rNTkjXyFNwVDBSMEYxrFQsDSCsdXV//8HAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>61</s> 60 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [TheLethalCoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38550/thelethalcoder)*

```cs
a=>a.Reverse().Zip(a,(x,y)=>x+y).ToArray()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBS8NAEIXP5lc8etpgkoKoCGkKRfCiXqogWDws20m70O7G3U1sKPntcZMUtVXfZWZ5b79hRthYaEOt4luyBReEp9o62gb7AF6llWqFB6ne0/4tNtxazPp@SHSyjjspUGm5xCOXioVf1neo012pxEQqt3iL0JcpcmQtRzYFT@ZUkbHEwuRVFoxHYLsIddiZO5z7LnnWM2N4zcL2rMOlR/CKGw8tSocMij6GAdjjKsLFZYQbX6/RpBiPMYnjQ3SlyWJNhoJfLF26AZazPhsej8v92bhYs36spx3y4cnKnW61snpDyYuRjpj0u4wwOsE1wb8//Pn9UdI/A3Piy3uqf9oDqQma9hM)

Byte count also includes:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

For explanation - Zip function in LINQ takes two collections and executes given function for all corresponding elements, ie. both first elements together, both second elements etc.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks for the comment about the input.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! You don't need the trailing semi colon in the byte count. I believe you can return the collection straight from the `Zip` call to so no need for the `ToArray()`. Nice job!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Thanks, and I added ToArray() since the challenge is about arrays, so I wanted the self-contained lambda to be array -> array.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
Ḃ+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuIIrIiwiIiwiWzEsIDIsIDNdIl0=)

```
Ḃ+
Ḃ  # bifurcate, i.e. duplicate and reverse
 + # vectorized addition of two lists
```

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
{_W%.+}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/Oj5cVU@79n9dwv9oQwUjBeNYAA)

Comment: It outputs `""` for `[]`, that's weird. Not your fault just the language.

Comment: @NoahCristino That's CJam's representation of `[]`.

Comment: Yup, it's hard to have a standard output for my challenge since many languages display arrays differently especially `[]`, and `[4]`, so it's fine.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to djhurio*

```r
rev(l<-scan())+l
```

Reads from stdin; returns the vector; `numeric(0)` is the zero-length numeric vector for the empty list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1TCPHRrc4OTFPQ1NTO@f/fwA)

Comment: For an empty "array" it returns `numeric(0)`

Comment: @NoahCristino an empty vector is represented as `numeric(0)` in R.

Comment: That's fine. @LeakyNun

Comment: `rev(l<-scan())+l`, 16 bytes?

Comment: For the record, an [R+pryr functional alternative](https://tio.run/##K/qfbqP7v6CossjKKk2jKLVMo0JTu0Lzf7qGgSZXukayhqGOoamOsakmiGdoZaz5HwA) is just one byte longer: `pryr::f(rev(x)+x)`

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

```apl
⌽+⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/FR24RHPXu1H3UtAnIUTBWMTBQsTBXMAA)

#### Explanation

```apl
⌽          The argument reversed
+           Plus
⊢          The argument
```

Comment: ninja'd. I need to move to an APL keyboard... xD

Comment: @Uriel I am always on my APL keyboard :D

Comment: Love the simplicity. It outputs `⌽+⊢` with no input

Comment: @NoahCristino An empty input is specified with `⍬`, the empty vector. With no argument, it prints the train by itself

Answer (score 4):

## Clojure, <s>20</s> 17 bytes

3 bytes saved thanks to @MattPutnam

```
#(map +(rseq %)%)
```

Seems to be quite competitive with non-golfing languages.

[See it online](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/X6OgKDOvREEjN7GgjEtBGUQraGsUFacWKqhqqmpyKURHWyhYGsUqRBsqGCkYA2lTBSMTBQtTBTMgG4gsLS1jY7kUNDX//wcA)

Comment: Use `rseq` instead of `reverse`.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
+V_
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BV_&input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D&debug=0)

Comment: Yay passes all my tests!

Comment: Equivalent: `sV_`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder nevermind

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>40</s> 32 bytes

```powershell
($n=$args)|%{$n[-++$i]+$n[$i-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0Mlz1YlsSi9WLNGtVolL1pXW1slM1YbyFLJ1DWMrf3//7/pfyOT/xam/80A)

Takes input as individual command-line arguments, which is allowed as one of the native list format for PowerShell. Then loops through each element (i.e., a shorter way of looping through the indices), adding the element counting from the back (`-1` indexed) to the current element (`0` indexed, hence the decrement `-1`). Those are left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Saved 8 bytes thanks to @briantist

Comment: it doesn't output an array.

Comment: @NoahCristino PowerShell input/output is, in general, weird. It *is* outputting as an array, it's just there's nothing capturing said array, and so when the implicit `Write-Output` happens, it puts things on stdout one item per line. For example, [you can see here](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPUyXRVsNQT08lTy85vzSvpEa1WiUvWlclPlYbRIMYtZrWKol66aklIZUFqRqa////d9Aw1TEy0bEw1THTBAA "PowerShell – Try It Online") that, when captured, the object is indeed an `array` type.

Comment: Good enough then :) atleast it tried

Comment: I'm on mobile and can't test so easily, but isn't it 1 byte shorter to remove the `param` and then replace `1..$n` with `1..($n=$args)`?

Comment: @briantist Not quite, but you did give me a different way of thinking about it, saving a bunch of bytes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 26 bytes

```powershell
($a=$args)|%{+$a[--$i]+$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0Ml0VYlsSi9WLNGtVpbJTFaV1clM1ZbJb72////pv@NTP5bmP43AwA)

Takes input as command-line arguments.

Comment: Can you add a TIO? and a link under the name like this one: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135427/61877

Comment: @NoahCristino: Like this? Haven't used that thing so far, so no idea what I may have done wrong. By the way, if you expect people to use a certain service in their answers, then please state so in the task description.

Comment: That's fine. It's not required it just makes the answers more high quality, and easier to test out for future viewers.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 49 bytes

```c
f(a,n,b)int*a,*b;{for(b=a+n;a<b--;a++)*a=*b+=*a;}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `a,n,b` be `a,b,n` or something?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No, `b` isn't a parameter for the function, just an extra definition stuffed in there for golfing reasons. `a` must be a pointer to integers, and `n` must be how many integers there are in the array.

Comment: Could you please add a TIO link?

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>61</s> <s>57</s> <s>56</s> 53 bytes

```java
a->{for(int l=0,r=a.length;l<r;a[l]=a[--r]+=a[l++]);}
```

-1 byte and bug-fixed thanks to *@Nevay*.
-3 bytes thanks to *@OliverGrégoire*.

(It was a port of (and golfed by <s>4</s> 8 bytes) of [*@jkelm*'s C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135447/52210), but now it's a different shorter solution thanks to *@OliverGrégoire*.)

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##tZDBboMwEETv@Yo9grCtloYE5FKpH9BcckQcXOKkpsZGxqSKEN9ODebWa5FsWTsavRlvze4M65ar@vI9iabVxkLtNNJbIcm7MezR0V0lWdfBBxNq2AEIZbm5sorDaR4B7lpcoAqcXpTAQurE0V13OsusqOAECnKYGH4brtrMRpD5EzI5I5Krm/2i8tVQVsgyZwXGpozcK6OoDOk4UY9q@0/pUCtxiWxcoeBsjVC3Jdi3WWvM1V2o4j9eGVKUxSNdLIpUwWII/Xx@dJY3RPeWtI5mpQr814nVnr/aV/9f@DOK0ctm9ATFe5Qm6LBZwmbgLMs2XDp2W0d4jxKED@iIcPovWeNunH4B)

The method modifies the input-array to save bytes, so no need for a return-type.

```java
a->{                    // Method with integer-array parameter and no return-type
  for(int l=0,          //  Left-integer (starting at 0)
          r=a.length;   //  Right-integer (starting at the length of the input-array)
      l<r;              //  Loop as long as left is smaller than right
    a[l]=               //   Change the number at the current left index to:
         a[--r]+=a[l++] //    The number at the right index + itself
                        //    (The += adds the number at the left index also to the right index)
                        //    (And the --/++ increases/decreases the indexes by 1,
                        //     until we've reached the middle of the array)
  );                    //  End of loop
}                       // End of method
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by using `a->{for(int i=0,l=a.length;i<l/2;a[i]=a[l+~i]+=a[i++]);}`.

Comment: Besides that the code fails for arrays with an odd length `1,2,3` (returns `4,2,4` instead of `4,4,4`), the loop has to run as long as `2*i<l`, not `i<l/2`.

Comment: @Nevay Thanks. I knew it should be possible to golf `l-i-1`, just couldn't come up with it..

Comment: 53 bytes: `a->{for(int l=0,r=a.length;l<r;a[l]=a[--r]+=a[l++]);}`.

Comment: Sorry for the not-identical variable names (short for left and right): I was implementing it by myself before seeing that you had posted an answer.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks. And your `l` and `r` makes sense for your implementation, so I've used those as well (and added an explanation).

Answer (score 3):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/) / [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 5 bytes

**Solution:**

```
x+|x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v0K7psLKUMFIwfj/fwA)

**Example:**

```
x+|x:,()
,()
x+|x:8 92
100 100
x+|x:,999
,1998
```

**Explanation:**

Not quite as elegant as the `J` solution, but same kinda thing:

```
x+|x: / the solution
   x: / store input as x
  |   / reverse it
 +    / add to
x     / x
```

Comment: Nice! I like the line by line explanation

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 18 bytes

```
[ dup reverse v+ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxCsIwGAb3PsW3CwWrlUYfQFxcxEkcQv3UYprGP2mgSp892g4Hd8PddR06SefT4bjf4kWxNPB897Q1PR60FG2ajw5NZz1aHZ555PR4OGEIg5PGBuyy7IsKqsD4lyUKrGYrUaxRldjMNaGUwpguuPUOwkjxRFzgmkpY7ZwZkHvUhlrSDw)

### Explanation

```
         ! { 1 2 3 }
dup      ! { 1 2 3 } { 1 2 3 }
reverse  ! { 1 2 3 } { 3 2 1 }
v+       ! { 4 4 4 }
```

Answer (score 3):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), <sup>44</sup> 39 bytes

```lisp
(load library
(q((p)(map* a p(reverse p
```

-5 bytes thanks to @DLosc

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYm7DYAgFEV7prjl004UAwu4BwYKEtQnGBOmxyDd@TzhLDFkrpXiZR1i2JNNRZDDRjcRD3RYHmHBlPzrU/bgSu1pGCl@miAxd1SQC7TC2rQnY0z9AA)

### Explanation

An anonymous function that maps the `a` function (addition) over pairwise elements in the input and the reverse of the input, forming a new list.

Comment: `map*` is your friend here: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYm7DYAgFEV7prjl004UAwu4BwYKEtQnGBOmxyDd@TzhLDFkrpXiZR1i2JNNRZDDRjcRD3RYHmHBlPzrU/bgSu1pGCl@miAxd1SQC7TC2rQnY0z9AA "tinylisp – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 6 bytes

```
{x+|x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6qu0K6pqOXiSlMwVDBSMFbQV9C1UzABQaCQhYKlEUTE0MAAhIFipgpGJgoWpgpmUAlDoLglBBsCpTU0IeIamkCOpaUlVJWlpQUAsgUUwQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to @ETHproductions.

```
a=>a.map((e,i)=>e+a[a.length+~i])
```

```js
let f=

a=>a.map((e,i)=>e+a[a.length+~i])

console.log(f([8,92]));
console.log(f([1,2,3]));
console.log(f([5, 24, 85, 6]));
console.log(f([]));
console.log(f([999]));
```

Comment: I love how you put in the test cases, +2

Comment: I think you can save a byte by changing `-i-1` to `+~i`.

Comment: @ETHproductions, yes, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 3 bytes

```
DR+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f/fJUj7//9oQx0FIx0F41gA)

Comment: It outputs floats, but I never said it couldn't, so that's fine, and for `[]` it doesn't output anything but that's just the language.

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 4 bytes

```
;R♀+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9866NHMBu3//6MNdRSMdBSMYwE)

Comment: Perfect, great job.

Comment: Erik, solving my problem in like 7 languages xD

Comment: @NoahCristino Yeah I'm trying to keep it under 15...;)

Comment: I'm going to have to start adding a -1 for every submission xD

Answer (score 2):

## [anyfix](https://github.com/alexander-liao/anyfix), 3 bytes

```
"U+
```

The version on TryItOnline! is an outdated version of anyfix, which contains a few fatal errors such as not being able to add lists because of typos in the source code. Use the code on GitHub instead.

```
"U+  Program
"    Duplicate top of stack
 U   Reverse top of stack if it is a list (which it should be...)
  +  Add, vectorizing for lists
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 22 bytes

```
{reverse(_)<>_1|[_+_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfyfFvO/uii1LLWoOFUjXtPGLt6wJjpeOz629n9uYmZeNVd0tKmOkYmOhamOWWxsTRpQUieBKyGWq/Y/AA)

This is an anonymous function that takes in an array and returns a stream of values, which the TIO link outputs separated over newlines.

#### Explanation

```
reverse(_)          The array reversed
<>                  interleaved with
_1                  the array itself
                    Push each element to the stream
[_+_]               Pull two values and push their sum
```

Comment: Passes my tests! Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 2 bytes

This is a function that takes input on the top of the stack and outputs on the top of the stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP2vZqhgpGCs@f/D3KmTP8ydsvv/fwA)

Comment: Is it allowed to modify the input stack via actual Neim code instead of normal input methods?

Comment: @LiefdeWen Yes, that's allowed in the defaults for I/O meta post.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
tP+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyRA@///aEMFIwXjWAA)

Extremely straightforward. `t` duplicates the input. `P` flips (reverses) it, and `+` adds the two arrays element wise.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 59 bytes

```php
for(;a&$c=$argv[++$i];)$a[]=$c+$argv[$argc-$i];print_r($a);
```

takes input from command line arguments; empty output for empty input

Yields a warning in PHP>7.0. This version does not (60 bytes):

```php
for(;++$i<$argc;)$a[]=$argv[$i]+$argv[$argc-$i];print_r($a);
```

Comment: Nice answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift 3](https://repl.it/Jjgy), 30 bytes

```
{zip($0,$0.reversed()).map(+)}
```

Comment: Can you add a try link?

Comment: @NoahCristino Done

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a snippet. Since Swift has no useful input method, you must take the input as a function. Hardcoding the input into a variable is disallowed by meta consensus. See [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for more details. That's the reason I incorporated my answer into a function, too.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder `{zip($0,$0.reversed()).map(+)}` 30 bytes

Comment: @Alexander You should edit your answer.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder That's not a particularly sensible distinction to make. It just forces people into using languages specifically designed to circumvent this, by implicitly taking input from STDIN, implicitly printing last return value, and crap like that

Comment: @Alexander Please trust me when I say hardcoding is not allowed. I think this is a great answer once it fits the default I/O rules

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder It's not that I don't trust you, I just take issue with the rules. If people are allowed to design languages with implicit input capabilities, why is it disallowed to mimic the behavior with a repl with predefined variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62869/discussion-between-mr-xcoder-and-alexander).

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 21 bytes

```
:zip%:reverse|:*&:sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9ItTar8n2b736oqs0DVqii1LLWoOLXGSkvNqrg093@BQpqeRrSFjqVRrCYXhGOoo2Cko2AM55sC@SY6ChZA2gwuCGdYWlrGav4HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## HP 48 User REPL, 19 bytes

```
« DUP REVLIST +
»
```

### Explanation

`«` and `»` mark the object as a program.

`DUP` - Duplicates the list

`REVLIST` - Reverses the list

`+` - Sums them

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.readthedocs.io), 5 bytes

```
sMC_B
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sMC_B&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D&debug=0)

Comment: Passed all my tests, congrats!

Comment: @NoahCristino Thanks, unfortunately got outgolfed

Answer (score 1):

## [Positron](https://github.com/alexander-liao/positron), 59 bytes

```
->{a=[]i=0;while(i<len@$1)do{a+=[$1@i+($1@(-(i+1)))]i++};a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcQxCoAgFADQyzgoXyGLJjO8hzgICX0QFRMaxLNbb3glP9hqTrNUTM1McXavrUO9qPfGGCgeMSRDJLty96AtkQaB/lNBESRjzCHAUH5MYyVf@cZ3Nz8)

This has many golfing opportunities that have been ruined by Positron's brokenness :P

Comment: Never heard of Positron before, but it passes all the tests :)

Comment: @NoahCristino It's a really hacky and horribly malfunctioning language that I made :)

Comment: It would be cool to golf in you're own language lol

Comment: @NoahCristino It is quite cool, but it would be cooler if it actually worked properly :))) :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby 2.4](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

Hooray, TIO supports Ruby 2.4 now!

```ruby
->a{a.zip(a.reverse).map &:sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cusTpRryqzQCNRryi1LLWoOFVTLzexQEHNqrg0t/Z/gUJadGpZYo5CempJcez/aEMdYx0jHXMdg1gA)

Comment: Passes all cases, good job!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 15 bytes

```
{$_ Z+.reverse}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiVeIUpbryi1LLWoOLX2v7VCcWKlQpqGjamCkYmChamCmZ2m9X8A)

Comment: Works! Good job.

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), <s>76</s> <s>68</s> 58 bytes (returns an Array)

*-8 bytes thanks to @[Alexander](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11490/alexander).*

```swift
func f(l:[Int]){print(zip(l,l.reversed()).map(+))}
```

[Try it online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5978cf8105543472066ad144)

---

## [Swift](https://swift.org), <s>76</s> 66 bytes

```swift
func f(l:[Int]){for i in 0..<l.count{print(l.reversed()[i]+l[i])}}
```

[Try it online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59763e647d75206f08ffca99)

Prints the sums separated by a newline. For `[1,2,3]`, the output is:

```swift
4
4
4
```

Comment: Works perfect good job

Comment: You can just use `map(+)`

Comment: @Alexander Welcome to PPCG! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform),<strike>65</strike> 57 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```cs
n=>{for(int i=0,o=n.Length;i<o/2;)n[i]=n[o-1-i]+=n[i++];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY09T8MwEIbn@Ffc1kSxCy0fRXJdCbHCgBgYogyWcdNTmzspNkUo8m8PbpAYeKfTc3fv44JyPPjpMyB18PYdou@1EO5kQ4BXMQrICdFGdHBm/IAXi1RW8Lu45NFFZNoixabdQQcGJjK7cc9DmRmguZZsaPnsqYsHjVu@WuuKGmwNNaxWCts6T1jXrU5TVhdnO0BvyH/B3DmupFrLG6lu5Z1U93Ij1UPSf/qu7Cstiqzz1h1m5TE/Ql@NoiiemAKf/PJ9wOjL4@XyH1vAItOU@VyZRJp@AA)

Comment: How do I input into this?

Comment: It throws 18 errors for me.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Since it's C, that's probably just 1 error.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino: It's C#.

Comment: @Joey close enough :P

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Fixed the TiO link, there was an opening brace missing.

Comment: @Ventero I didn't downvote though

Comment: @NoahCristino it's a lambda. Assign it to a variable like `var a = n=>...` and then try `a(<your_array_here>)`

Comment: You can golf 4 bytes by changing `=n[i]=n[i]+` to `=n[i]+=`. And judging by the previous comments a bracket was missing causing some errors/confusion, so I'll +1 to neutralize the downvote (not by me!) now that that's fixed.

Comment: Just created [a port of your answer in Java 8](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139268/52210), and I noticed you can golf 4 more bytes by swapping the `n[o-1-i]` and `n[i]`, so you'll use the shorter `n[i]` twice instead of `n[o-1-i]`. So it will become this: `n=>{for(int i=0,o=n.Length;i<o/2;)n[i]=n[o-1-i]+=n[i++];}` (**57 bytes**)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for the golfing. I didn't even think of the += there for some reason.

Comment: @jkelm No problem. Also, _Nevay_ golfed one more by in my Java 8 answer, and also bug-fixed incorrect results for odd-length lists (i.e. `1,2,3` currently returns `4,1,4` instead of `4,4,4`). `o-1-i` can be `o+~i` for -1 byte; and `i<o/2` should be `i*2<o` to fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 + [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), 31 bytes

I think this is kosher based on the rules, but let me know if not.

Anonymous function takes a `numpy` array as input:

```
import numpy
lambda l:l+l[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcq7CoAgFADQva9wTLoF2QMV@pJwMEISfCE2@PUWzTmfE3K6vCOlaBt8TMjdNuRGbUba45TIcNOZnfN@FCVE7RJS7VcGGaPM7U6BEYFx84sjEJiqugCZgS6wVkcVGGOvlQc)

Comment: It works, but why does it output so weird? Some are like: `[4 4 4]` which is already weird for python, and then one is like `[ 11 109 109  11]`???

Comment: Probably because its a `numpy` array rather than a list

Comment: It's allowed but please specify that you are using numpy in the header next time. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: @totallyhuman, I haven't seen that on other posts, but I'll keep it in mind from here on out, thanks for the edit!

Comment: Looks weird, but it works.

Comment: @NoahCristino, that's what this site is all about, right?

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that if you use an external library that doesn't come packaged with the language, it should be added to the header. So you don't need to mention `urllib2` because it comes included with Python, but [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) will need to be mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```
(lambda(l)(map +(reverse l)l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HccxCoAwDAXQvacIOPiDk3qiaBMR0yJRvH4V3/ZC1kPv1rnUjeJPQlbbq5I1uJQlC5xR5KQBoY/GpeTszI0TjHqMNNH89QU)

This is simply an anonymous function that maps corresponding elements from `l` and `l` reversed to the `+` function, returning the results in a list.

Comment: Works fine, good job.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 31 bytes

```
\d+
$*1;$&$*
O$^`;1+

;

1+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JkWbS0XL0FpFTUWLy18lLsHaUJuLy5qLC0ip6Kn9/2@qYGSiYGGqYAYA) Explanation:

```
\d+
$*1;$&$*
```

Convert to unary and duplicate each element.

```
O$^`;1+
```

Reverse the order of the duplicate elements.

```
;
```

Add the elements to their reversed duplicates.

```
1+
$.&
```

Convert the elements back to decimal.

Comment: Good answer, but does your code need the newlines? or could it be squished into 1 line?

Comment: @NoahCristino No, in Retina the newlines normally delimit statements. (The exception is the command-line option to place each statement in a separate file.)

Answer (score 1):

## x86 Machine Code (32-bit protected mode), 19 bytes

```
8D 34 B7 39 F7 73 0C 83 EE 04 8B 07 03 06 89 06 AB EB F0 C3
```

The above bytes of code define a function that takes two parameters (a pointer to the array in the `EDI` register, and the length of the array in the `ESI` register), modifies the pointed-to array to contain the "reverse array sum", and then returns. It does not return a value to the caller.

(This is a custom calling convention used to receive the arguments. It is actually the standard calling convention used on Gnu/Unix systems for x86-64 binaries, but in x86-32, arguments are typically passed on the stack. That takes more bytes to encode, and is less efficient, so we want to ensure that the arguments are passed to us in registers. As far as I understand the rules, this is completely legal. We don't need to conform to a particular standardized calling convention. Certainly, when writing assembly, the programmer is free to define her own calling conventions, unless she needs to interoperate with C code.)

Note that this function also assumes the direction flag is cleared (`DF` == 0) upon entry to the function. This is a sensible assumption, as it is guaranteed by most platform ABIs, including the Linux x86 32-bit ABI. If you need the code to work under circumstances where the state of `DF` cannot be assumed, then you need to add a 1-byte `CLD` instruction to the top of the function.

**Ungolfed assembly mnemonics:**

```
               ; void ReverseArraySum(int *pArray, int length);
8D 34 B7         lea    esi, [edi+esi*4]        ; compute back pointer
               Loop:
39 F7            cmp    edi, esi
73 0C            jae    End                     ; finished when EDI >= ESI
83 EE 04         sub    esi, 4
8B 07            mov    eax, DWORD PTR [edi]
03 06            add    eax, DWORD PTR [esi]
89 06            mov    DWORD PTR [esi], eax
AB               stosd  ; equivalent to 'mov DWORD PTR es:[edi], eax' + 'add edi, 4'
EB F0            jmp    Loop
               End:
C3               ret
```

Conceptually, the code is pretty straightforward. **We just iterate through the array using two pointers.** The first pointer is passed to us as an argument, in the register `EDI`, and it is a pointer to the beginning of the array. The second pointer is computed (initial `LEA` instruction) by adding the address of the beginning of the array to the length of the array, scaled by the size of an element in the array (4 bytes for an `int` on x86-32). Thus, `ESI` is a pointer to the *end* of the array.

At the top of the `Loop`, we check the pointers to see if we should keep looping or if we are finished. Normally, we'd want to save bytes by putting this test at the *end* of the loop (and eliminating the `JMP` you see at the end now), but we can't do that because the challenge requires us to handle an empty input array.

Inside the body of the loop, we:

- Eagerly subtract 4 bytes (the size of a single element in the array) from the back pointer, `ESI`.
- Retrieve and store the value of the element pointed to by the front pointer (`EDI`) in a temporary register (`EAX`).
- Increment `EAX` by the value of the element pointed to by the back pointer (`ESI`).
- Store the sum (`EAX`) in the element pointed to by the back pointer (`ESI`).
- Store the same sum (`EAX`) in the element pointed to by the front pointer (`EDI`), *while simultaneously* incrementing that pointer (`EDI`) by 4 bytes (the size of a single element in the array). The handy x86 string instruction `STOSD` is what allows us to do both of those things in only a single byte of code.
  <sub>(With the caveat given at the outset, that the direction flag is cleared, and also the assumption that we are running in *flat* mode, where the "extra" segment (`ES`) is identical to the data segment (`DS`).)</sub>

Finally, we're done and we return to the caller, without returning any value.

__
You can see it run on [TIO](https://tio.run/##bZFNb6MwEIbP@FeMWK0ELe2yIZuAaFdq00TaWw@9xTkQ22kttaYCZ@XdiL9eOiaui6IKwfh955kPC3bxyFjfs1q1GthT1YDJZ4uai/UGriGkJr@lZr6gZjKlJp06PXU6R31HTYbn2znGgpoVxnmGOazJMS6Xn3Up5lKbm6EujvEG/SW@q5SaRRaWpNWVlgz@1pJDdIbbrIyKI6n0WQL4jXEtt2LZf5OKPe@5gKtWc1lfPv0mZCi8bxC9aZrq31AJ1VALKiYHErza5C4KDxDGJQl2dQOWAomt0xLDFagSzs9lTALEPf@dJxAmUK3lxtZ1n50626hzsx9Eq//oL@aOlkJf2R7H63n50Y8qqu0z7PdF2etet1HohtoBL5VU0TDEqmr4eQfIEygm0JVHd@vcnwlMEsi8z5z/C/1pAjnGmU9yl/zQwumiKKxHAndb3KyV/0W9i6oYfvjzOt3EdmFHbT21HVHbE4p5io0odkJxT/ERxU8o4SkxooSjSNAIvW8U/nbS9W9s91w9tv3FSzZ5Bw), but note that the TIO link uses a C wrapper to exercise the machine code, and GCC won't necessarily respect our custom calling convention, so we have to add extra code at the top of the function to retrieve the parameters from the stack and put them into the appropriate registers.

Comment: Interesting language choice!

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, SBCL, 33 bytes

Pretty simple solution (very similiar to Clojure one):

```
(lambda(x)(mapcar'+(reverse x)x))
```

Example of use:

```
((lambda(x)(mapcar'+(reverse x)x))'(1 2 3)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcFBDoAwCATAr3DrEk/qi7ByaNI2hBrD79GZ2tuyTJi3@QBdxnULgjHEqnjZ4PqqL6XgYC7Y6aCTf5kf)(with `print` function, to show output from function)

Answer (score 1):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src/c7c22d0f78077348223c176a543b3ca00720247e/codepage.txt?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 5 bytes

```
ωω⌽+←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//985/nORz17tR@1Tfj//3@0oY6RjnEsAA)

**How?**

First, you bang your head against the wall after remembering that addition on strings isn't commutative. Then, you bang your head yet again after realizing that you could've used `ω` to save over 40 bytes! Finally, you arrive at this:

```
ω    - First command line argument
ω⌽   - First command line argument, reversed
+    - Add (vectorizes)
←    - Output without a newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, 57 bytes

As generic unnamed lambda requiring a container and returns via modifying its input:

```cpp
[](auto&L){auto R=L;auto r=R.end();for(auto&x:L)x+=*--r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVCxboMwEN39FadUqqCYSqFJFWLMkpUpylZ1sIxBlsBG2ERIkX@91EDTds1yenfv3fk9866La86nJ6l4M5Qik9rYXrA2R7@jq@BW9zlCg5GqBsVaYTrGBRhbEoTYYDVUdPr4DGb4XIS3ZXSmBVlAT8@vQpVBSCrdr5rxWIRjRF/iuCdu8keuWpZghbELD0UINwR3OcxyrgcLWQbjXDYYNgTBfeavN76tgiIkD679rTuEpLLQMqkC/zwgWIP/5M88medwATpbg9sBp4nDM9riBL@tcI@THT7s8fvarjVNU4fA/Xd2Ol5CTy2BT96zm7541bDaTLH/VMqjaLv7Bg)

Ungolfed:

```cpp
[](auto&L){
 auto R=L;      //copy of the list
 auto r=R.end();//iterator of last+1
 for(auto&x:L)  //foreach
  x+=*--r;      //move iterator to front and sum
}
```

Comment: Nice job, can you include a try it link?

Comment: @NoahCristino sure, didnt know TIO can generate CodeGolf posts. Now i do :)

Answer (score 1):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 22 bytes

**Code**

```
clone a:rev ' n:+ a:op
```

**SED** (Stack Effect Diagram) is: `a -- a`

**Ungolfed code with comments**

```
: f \ a -- a 
  clone      \ clone array on TOS 
  a:rev      \ reverse array 
  ' n:+ a:op \ Add the corresponding elements of each array producing a new array
;
```

**Usage**

```
ok> [8,92] clone a:rev ' n:+ a:op .
[100,100]
```

**Test cases**

```
ok> [8,92] f .
[100,100]
ok> [1,2,3] f .
[4,4,4]
ok> [5,24,85,6] f .
[11,109,109,11]
ok> [] f .
[]
ok> [999] f .
[1998]
```

Comment: Never heard of this language before great job!

Answer (score 1):

## Casio-Basic, 25 bytes

```
l+seq(l[x],x,dim(l),1,-1
```

Addition threads over lists by default - but there's no built-in for reversing a list! `seq` is used to generate the reversed list by indexing backwards through it.

24 bytes for the function, +1 byte to add `l` in the parameters box.

Comment: Cool! I don't know much about this language, but is it possible to add a try it link?

Comment: There isn't really a way to try it online - but, if you're willing, you can download the 90 day free trial of the calculator emulator software from http://edu.casio.com/softwarelicense/index.php. If it redirects you to the home page, just click on software/app at the top right and get the appropriate ClassPad II Manager for your OS. :)

Comment: Cool! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 28 bytes

```lua
map(a,a+index(c,len(c)-b+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z83sUAjUSdROzMvJbVCI1knJzVPI1lTN0nbUFPz////1YY6CkY6CiY6Csa1AA)

Comment: Nice job, never heard of ARBLE!

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
òôΩo1
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9593ea6f31&i=[8,+92]%0A[1,+2,+3]%0A[5,+24,+85,+6]%0A[]%0A[999]&a=1&m=2)

I like that sequence of `o`-style chars `(òôΩo)`.

Explanation (unpacked):

```
cr\m|+ Full program, implicit input  e.g.: [1, 2, 3]
cr     Copy and reverse                    [1, 2, 3] [3, 2, 1]
  \    Zip                                 [[1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 1]]
   m|+ Map sum of array                    [4, 4, 4]
       Implicit output
```

Comment: Nice solution, never heard of Stax before!

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 8 bytes

```
L,dbRz£+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HJyUpqOrQYu3/KjmJuUkpiQqGdvZc/v//R8cCAA)

Finally something sane with Add++

### Explained

```
L,dbRz£+
L,        ; create a lambda that:
  dbR     ; pushes the input list and its reverse
     z    ; zips those together
      £+  ; and reduces each pair by addition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 4 bytes

```
g+Rg
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuhZL0rWD0iFMqMjqaFMdIxMdC1MdM5giAA)

#### Explanation

Just what it says on the tin.

```
   g  List of command-line arguments
  R   Reversed
g+    Add to the original list
```

(Addition operates element-wise on lists in Pip.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 7 bytes

```
0__2-?_+_?+_0
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIwX18yLT9fK18_K18wIiwiW1sxLCAyLCAzXV0iLDBd)

Appends `-?` (first input reversed) to `__` (all inputs, which is in this case a trick to wrap the input array), and then transposes. Maps with sum, which is the most complicated usage of Risky's quicks that I'm even going to attempt.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 22 bytes

```
f(l)=l+l[l.length...1]
```

Pretty self-explanatory

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zjl9ahjptd)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f1trwbj7hy)

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 14 bytes

```
:zip%:~|:*&+:+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboW66yqMgtUrepqrLTUtK20IYLbChTcoqMNdRQMDXQUTCCUYWwsRHLBAggNAA)

```
:zip % :~ |           # Zip array with its reverse, then
            :* & +:+  # Map with sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
r+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi4q0lxQnJRdDuQvWRZvqKBiZ6ChYAGmzWIgoAA)

`r` is reverse and `+` is add.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 7 bytes

```
[:rev+]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYhLCoAgAAX3neJBQUptsg8qFN0jWkgpVFRin@tbLt4M865bTZuevR@k0282@l6aiJACDCWNQDgEC67BKvAaTYgwIQSlGCQM4hyJ09ZhVxYp2u7Hei4Hzucew@k/)

Just adding to the reversed.

Comment: Easy to understand! Output is ok I guess.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 49 bytes

```
lmap l $L r [lreverse $L] {lappend N [incr l $r]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEAXQq/yFJ4iMDiFeQFyIzSKYREZrI559quWD1zNrow6HYbGs2C22qXylCoZxEAQWekgafYwYnGqlcsAjnCXLvyROrXdvMF5f)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 14 bytes

```
a->a+Vecrev(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fck7CoAwEATQqwxWBjeF8YMp9Bg2kmIRFUFkCSJ4@rgphnnDCMfTHpJ2jEhsJ67mbY3bW7JJLHJ9JcNOkHjej7LIo8CutyEsy0DwLqhqgiM0mZ2yJQzafd453vsQTPoB)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 49 bytes

```
(a:Seq[Int])=>a.zip(a.reverse)map{case(a,b)=>a+b}
```

Lambda. Paste in the REPL, it gets assigned to a default variable, like `res0` or whatever. Note the variable name from the output produced after pasting that line into the REPL and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, let's say it's `res4`. To call the lambda, just use `res4(Seq(1, 2, 3))` or `res4(Seq(89, 88, 1, 2, 3, 1000, 2000))` for the test cases.

#### Implementation notes:

`zip` creates a `Tuple2` from 2 `Seq`s, which need to be unpacked in the pattern match (the `case` expression after the `map`) before the elements can be added. Indexed access is convoluted for golfing in Scala...

Here's another version, using convoluted indexing tricks for 57 bytes:

```
(a:Seq[Int])=>{val l=a.size-1;0.to(l)map(i=>a(i)+a(l-i))}
```

This just produces a new `Seq` from adding the "complementary" elements of the `Seq`s (symmetrically about the mid of the `Seq`. Very imperative.

I don't like it either, but the type ascriptions are necessary to get the REPL to accept it, otherwise it just botches out `Missing Parameter Type`.

The idea in the 2nd version can be used in Java 8 as well, just swapping in `IntStream.rangeClosed(0,l)` instead of Scala's implicit `to` on `Int`s, unlike the former, which would be considerably more convoluted in Java.

Note that @jkelm's answer for C# can be trivially translated to Java.

Answer (score 0):

## R: 19 bytes

function(v)rev(v)+v

Try It Out:
http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=vJhwqK77

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site.  I don't know R very well This looks like what is called a snippet which we do not allow for answers here.  Your answer may be either a function (anonymous or named) or a full program.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 21 bytes

```clj
#(map + %(reverse %))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vUVCUmVeSk6eg8V9ZIzexQEFbQVWjKLUstag4VUFVU/O/grqGoYKRgrEmkA0A)

Having trouble golfing this any further. Any clever ideas?

Comment: There's already a similar answer a little ahead of you. Flip the last two args to eliminate a space, and use `rseq` instead of `reverse`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
Sz+↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P7hK@1HblP///0cb6hjpGMcCAA) (Note if you want to test with empty list, you need to supply: `[]:LN` as argument)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

```
      -- implicit input list        - [1,2,3]
S     -- "duplicate input and"      - [1,2,3] [1,2,3]
   ↔  -- reverse one copy           - [1,2,3] [3,2,1]
 z+   -- zip with original using +  - [1+3,2+2,3+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 24 + 1 (-a) = 25 bytes

```perl
print$_+$F[--$i],$"for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRCVeW8UtWldXJTNWR0UpLb/Iwe3/f0MFIwVjBRMF03/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6yYCAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 3 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
+⇌.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgK-KHjC4KCmYgWzggOTJdCmYgWzEgMiAzXQpmIFs1IDI0IDg1IDZdCmYgW10KZiBbOTk5XQ==)

```
+⇌.
  .  # duplicate
 ⇌   # reverse
+    # add
```

Answer (score -2):

## J, 5 bytes

```
(+|.)

    (+|.) 1 2 3    ===> 4 4 4
    (+|.) 89 98 1 2 3 1000 2000  =====> 2089 1098 4 4 4 1098 2089

    NB. Does not work without the parentheses as per previous answer by @Jonah
```

Comment: While there's no shame in arriving independently at an answer that is identical to someone else's, this isn't the case here. `+|.` is valid on its own, so this is just a less golfed version of Jonah's answer.